# iphone landscape mode scroll textField up

Tags: iphone

I have this function for scrolling the textFields on the page up when the keyboard pops up but it doesn't work right for landscape mode. It still scrolls towards the top of the iphone (where the ear piece is, if that makes sense. So it looks like it's scrolling to the side when done in landscape mode) in landscape mode rather than scrolling as it should. How would I modify this function to make it scroll correctly and only in landscape mode? I don't need it to scroll at all in portrait mode. Thanks!

```
static const CGFloat KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.3;
static const CGFloat MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.2;
static const CGFloat MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.8;
static const CGFloat PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 216;
static const CGFloat LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 162;

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
CGRect textFieldRect =
[self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
CGRect viewRect =
[self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];

CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;
CGFloat numerator =
midline - viewRect.origin.y
- MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;
CGFloat denominator =
(MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION)
* viewRect.size.height;
CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;

if (heightFraction < 0.0)
{
    heightFraction = 0.0;
}
else if (heightFraction > 1.0)
{
    heightFraction = 1.0;
}

UIInterfaceOrientation orientation =
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
    orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{
    animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"LANDSCAPE");
    animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
}


CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

[self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

[UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
viewFrame.origin.y += animatedDistance;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

[self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Nevermind! I got it to work after all! I didn't realize it was always moving in the y direction. All I had to do was change the direction it was moving everything and add an if statement in the function so it would only move if in landscape mode.

Comment: If you could update your question with the answer, that would be great.

Comment: Alright, I did that. Is there anyway to mark the question as solved?

Comment: Sorry, the normal way is to add the answer into the box below and then mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static const CGFloat KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.3;
static const CGFloat MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.2;
static const CGFloat MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.8;
static const CGFloat LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 162;

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation =
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || 
    orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) 
{

    CGRect textFieldRect =
    [self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
    CGRect viewRect =
    [self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];

    CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;
    CGFloat numerator =
    midline - viewRect.origin.y
    - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat denominator =
    (MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION)
    * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;

    if (heightFraction < 0.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 0.0;
    }
    else if (heightFraction > 1.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 1.0;
    }

    animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);

    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;

    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) 
    {
        viewFrame.origin.x -= animatedDistance;
    }
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) 
    {
        viewFrame.origin.x += animatedDistance;
    }

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
}
// scrolls the view down if the view was scrolled up 
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation =
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || 
    orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) 
{
    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;

    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) 
    {
        viewFrame.origin.x += animatedDistance;
    }
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) 
    {
        viewFrame.origin.x -= animatedDistance;
    }

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
}
```